# Spring Boot invalid CSS and JS path

Tags: spring, spring-boot

In my Spring Boot app for some reason CSS and JS files are looked up for in incorrect folder. This happens only on edit, when I use the same form for adding new objects everything works fine. As you can see in the console, there is additional 'editGame' element in the path. Where did it come from?

[image]

Comment: please to add you newGame.html code for more investigation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you add jquery and bootstrap on your project?

In my project i type as href="/css/style.css" instead of href="css/style.css" and it works.

Maybe thats the problem if you added required files.

Comment: Yep, it did help. Thanks!